# Disable an option inside a select tag in AngularJS form

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, frontend

I have a form, which has two selects. I'd like to achieve, that if the "Any" option is selected in the first select, disable one of the option in the other select.

So, right here, if "Any" (part of the vm.scriptTypes, vm is the controller) is selected:

```
<select name="scriptType" id="scriptType" class="form-control" required
        ng-model="vm.rule.scriptType"
        ng-options="option.name as option.name for option in vm.scriptTypes">
</select>
```

Disable "Combination ban" from the vm.actions (ng-options) ("Combination ban" is part of the vm.actions, it's an object, which has a "type" and a "command" key)

```
<select name="action" id="action" class="form-control" required
        ng-model="vm.rule.action"
        ng-change="vm.rule.action "
        ng-options="(option.type + ' ' + option.command) as (option.type + ' ' + option.command) for option in vm.actions">
</select>
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `disable when` argument in your ngOptions https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

```
<div ng-app="TestApp" ng-controller="TestController">
  <select name="scriptType" id="scriptType" class="form-control" required
          ng-model="rule.scriptType"
          ng-options="option.name as option.name for option in scriptTypes">
  </select>
  <select name="action" id="action" class="form-control" required
        ng-model="rule.action"
        ng-change="rule.action "
        ng-options="(option.type + ' ' + option.command) as (option.type + ' ' + option.command) disable when (rule.scriptType == 'Any' && option.type == 'Combination ban') for option in actions">
</select>
</div>
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module('TestApp', []);

app.controller('TestController', function($scope) {
  $scope.scriptTypes = [{
    name: 'Any'
  },
  {
    name: 'ron'
  },
  {
    name: 'ron2'    
  }];
  $scope.actions = [{
    type: 'type1',
    command: 'cmd1',
  },
  {
    type: 'type2',
    command: 'cmd2',
  },
  {
    type: 'Combination ban',
    command: 'Combination ban',
  }];
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ojzdxpt1/59/

Comment: That's great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try option tags inside select?
For ex:

```
<select name="action" id="action" class="form-control" required
    ng-model="vm.rule.action"
    ng-change="vm.rule.action "
    ng-options="(option.type + ' ' + option.command) as (option.type + ' ' + option.command) for option in vm.actions">
    <option value="{{option.type + ' ' + option.command}}" ng-disabled="option.type == 'Combination ban' && vm.rule.scriptType == 'Any'">{{option.type + ' ' + option.command}}</option>
</select>
```

Please let me know if it does not work.
I didn't test it though.

Comment: This does not work, I wasn't able to figure out why. :\